# Converting JSON array to array for a UIPickerView

Tags: ios, nsarray

I need to populate a UIPickerView from objects from an array.

This is the output from the array that I am using as datasource for the picker view:

```
MESSAGEARRAY=
(
        {
        baggage = 4;
        id = 1;
        name = auto;
        passenger = 4;
        "resource_uri" = "/rest/type_vehicle/1/";
    },
        {
        baggage = 8;
        id = 2;
        name = miniban;
        passenger = 8;
        "resource_uri" = "/rest/type_vehicle/2/";
    },
        {
        baggage = 6;
        id = 3;
        name = camioneta;
        passenger = 6;
        "resource_uri" = "/rest/type_vehicle/3/";
    }
)
```

And this are the methods I am using to do it:

```
// The number of columns of data
- (int)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 4;
}

// The number of rows of data
- (int)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData.count;
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData[component][row];
}
```

But the app crashes with following error message:

```
[__NSDictionaryM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: _pickerData[component] returns one of the dictionaries in your array. You then try to access values in that dictionary by index ([row]) rather than by key, which is how you access things in a dictionary.

Comment: @rdelmar, thank you. If I change the line as follows: return [_pickerData[component] objectForKey:@"name"]; Then, the app crashes with error: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]. Then I change to return 3. And the picker shows the three objects, but one wheel per object. If I put return 1, then it shows i wheel with three objects but the same title on every object. Would you help me?

Comment: @rdelmar, it works now, please take a look at my answer. Thank you in any case.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem `_pickerData[component][row];`  `_pickerData[component]` returns a `NSDictionary` like this:

```
{
        baggage = 4;
        id = 1;
        name = auto;
        passenger = 4;
        "resource_uri" = "/rest/type_vehicle/1/";
}
```

You cannot ask for `NSDictionary[row]` because it is not an `NSArray`. Thats why you are getting this error.

Comment: Please take a look at my response to rdelmar, may be you can help me.

Comment: You have two items but you returning explicitly 4 here - `(int)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 4;
}`

Comment: What two items do you mean? I have 3 objects and each object has 4 keys.

Comment: It works now, please take a look at my answer. Thank you in any case.

Answer (score 0):

This error potentially means that you are working with a NSArray as NSDictionary, most likely you are getting dictionary here instead of an array

Please, debug it carefully and check if you are dealing with the expected types.

Comment: Please take a look at my response to rdelmar, may be you can help me.

Comment: It works now, please take a look at my answer. Thank you in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the wrong methods as follows:

```
- (int)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [_pickerData [row] objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

And now it works fine. 
Thank you.